# AS3/FLASH/AIR: Is it possible to open an XML in Excel? YES

Tags: xml, excel, actionscript-3, flash, air

Is it possible to open an XML in Excel from an AIR desktop application?

I have an XML database and I'd like to open it in Excel for printing. Printing the full data stored in a datagrid (flash component) is not possible, I think.

Thanks in advance.

**::::: UPDATE I :::::**

With the help of **null.point3r**, I'm finding Excel. Now I must try to understand how to open the XML with it.

He gave me the clue with links:

Lunch excel and open the XML file. (create a [**NativeProcess**](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/flash/desktop/NativeProcess.html) and pass the XML path as [**argument**](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/flash/desktop/NativeProcessStartupInfo.html#arguments)) [**command line switches for excel**](http://office.microsoft.com/en-us/excel-help/command-line-switches-for-excel-HA010158030.aspx#BM4).

But I'm new to that stuff so, if someone has an example I'll appreciate his help.

What I have until now:

```
import flash.filesystem.File;

var myXML = File.documentsDirectory.resolvePath("storage/companies.xml");

if(myXML.exists){
    trace ("Eureka!!!");
}

var excel:File = new File(); 
excel.nativePath = "C:\\Archivos de programa\\Microsoft Office\\Office12\\excel.exe";

if(excel.exists){
    trace ("Got it!!!");
}
//get executable(file.nativePath):File;
```

Note: I'll use an array and a loop to check differen Office versions.

**:::: UPDATE II ::::**

I'm getting Error #3219: The NativeProcess could not be started. 'Not supported in current profile.':

```
import flash.filesystem.File;

var myXML = File.documentsDirectory.resolvePath("storage/companies.xml");

if (myXML.exists) {
    trace(myXML.nativePath);
}

var process:NativeProcess;
var nativeProcessStartupInfo:NativeProcessStartupInfo = new NativeProcessStartupInfo();
var excel:File = new File();
excel.nativePath = "C:\\Archivos de programa\\Microsoft Office\\Office12\\excel.exe";

if (excel.exists) {
    trace(excel.nativePath);
}

nativeProcessStartupInfo.executable = excel;

var processArgs:Vector.<String> = new Vector.<String>();
processArgs[0] = String(myXML.nativePath);
nativeProcessStartupInfo.arguments = processArgs;

process = new NativeProcess();
process.start(nativeProcessStartupInfo);
```

Comment: What part is not working? Trying to open up Excel or getting the XML in there?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

- Check to see if excel [exists()](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/flash/filesystem/File.html#exists) in the default location:

  > C:\Program Files\Microsoft Office\Office**X** (**X** depends on office version)
- If you can't find it, display the [browseForOpen()](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/flash/filesystem/File.html#browseForOpen%28%29) dialog or prompt user to install it.
- Lunch excel and open the XML file. (create a [NativeProcess](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/flash/desktop/NativeProcess.html) and pass the XML path as [argument](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/flash/desktop/NativeProcessStartupInfo.html#arguments)) [command line switches for excel](http://office.microsoft.com/en-us/excel-help/command-line-switches-for-excel-HA010158030.aspx#BM4)

---

**UPDATE:**

```
var process:NativeProcess;
var nativeProcessStartupInfo:NativeProcessStartupInfo = new NativeProcessStartupInfo();
var excel:File = new File(); 
excel.nativePath = "path\to\excel";
if(excel.exists){
    trace (excel.nativePath);
}
nativeProcessStartupInfo.executable = excel;

var processArgs:Vector.<String> = new Vector.<String>();
processArgs[0] = "path\to\xml";
nativeProcessStartupInfo.arguments = processArgs;

process = new NativeProcess();
process.start(nativeProcessStartupInfo);
```

Comment: No problem finding Excel, so I can define it's possible path in an array: Office11, Office12... And search for it in a loop. Now I must see how to open the XML in Excel.

Comment: Many thanks null.point3r. I still don't know how to define "var processArgs:Vector.<String> = new Vector.<String>()". I must use: excel.exe "path\to\xml", doesn't it?

Comment: I'm getting Error #3219: The NativeProcess could not be started. 'Not supported in current profile.':

Comment: @Sergio, add `<supportedProfiles>extendedDesktop </supportedProfiles>` to [yourApp]-app.xml

Comment: Thanks null.point3r. I'll try later. Now I must go to the kinesiologist. cheers.

Comment: Now works like a charm. Many, many thanks for sharing null.point3r.